# Como genero un una matrix con una cantidad exacta de "X" en posiciones aleatorias en C#?

Tags: c#, random

Tengo que realizar un juego de la vida pero tengo el problema de que en el modo aleatorio el usuario debe de ingresar la cantidad de celulas vivas (las "X") para iniciar el juego y no se como ingresar una cantidad exacta de "X" en posiciones aleatorias dentro de mi matrix. Aqui esta un trozo del codigo:

```
public bool[,] matrix = new bool[tamX, tamY];
var random = new Random ();
        for (int x = 0; x < tamX; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < tamY; y++)
                matrix [x, y] = random.NextDouble () <= 0.20;
}
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no deberias randomizar la X y la Y?

Answer (score 2):

lo que puedes hacer es generar coordenadas X y Y aleatorias en un while loop e intentar poner una célula viva en esa posición si estaba muerta, hasta que X no sea 0. Si la célula en esa posición ya estaba muerta, la revives y disminuyes X sino generas otras coordenadas aleatorias.

Aquí puedes ver mi código para generar las células vivas e imprimir la tabla

```
    public class GameOfLife
{
    public bool[,] matrix;
    int tamX;
    int tamY;
    public GameOfLife(int tamX, int tamY, int X)
    {
        this.matrix = new bool[tamX, tamY];
        this.tamX = tamX;
        this.tamY = tamY;
        var random = new Random();

        while (X > 0)
        {
            int coordenadaX = random.Next(0, tamX);
            int coordenadaY = random.Next(0, tamY);

            if (!matrix[coordenadaX, coordenadaY])
            {
                matrix[coordenadaX, coordenadaY] = true;
                X--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< this.tamX;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < this.tamY; j++)
            {
                if (matrix[i, j])
                    Console.Write(1);
                else
                    Console.Write(0);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Espero haberte podido ser de ayuda

Comment: Siempre hay que recalcar y tomar en cuenta, que este programa asi como esta, puede no terminar nunca.. Como random es pseudoaleatorio y para una X demasiado grande, los numeros podrian repetirse y nunca encontrar una posicion random, ya que las mismas se empezarian a repetir.

Comment: me di cuenta, cuando pongo la cantidad de X que quiero algunas veces no llega a la cantidad que debe de llegar. supongo que eso pasa por que es aleatorio, espero que el profesor lo entienda ..